# when adding items into a dictionary from an array I get an error?? PYTHON 3.x

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

```
stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}



def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():

        print(str(v) + " " + k)
        item_total += v

    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total) + '\n')

displayInventory(stuff)

dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}

def addToInventory(ram, addedItems):

  for itemindex in addedItems:
    if itemindex not in ram:
      ram[itemindex] = 0

    ram[itemindex] = ram[itemindex] + 1

dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)

displayInventory(inv)
```

when I do this it returns an error like this ...

```
Inventory:
1 rope
6 torch
1 dagger
12 arrow
Total number of items: 62

Inventory:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 33, in <module>
  File "python", line 8, in displayInventory
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

this doesn't make sense, considering the fact that when you change the `inv` to `'abc'` or anything other than inv the error goes away and the code runs smoothly.

Comment: Please copy paste the console output, do not post an *image* of it.

Comment: The reason you get the error is because `addToInventory` does *not* return something *explicitly*, so it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `inv` to `displayInventory`, but since `addToInventory` doesn't return anything, `inv` is `None`, and as such has no attribute `items()`.

```
inv=addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot) #inv=None since addToInventory returns nothing
displayInventory(inv) #passing it None
    for k, v in inventory.items(): #None.items() is obviously invalid, creates error
```

Comment: @PaulHanamon When an answer solves your problem, You can click the green tick next to it. It lets others know that it is a valid answer, gives you 2rep and gives the answerer 15rep